# Obj-C- Add new row to TableView when cell is tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I've got a tableview that allows users to add an item (a row) to an invoice (the tableview) when an existing row is tapped. That said, I can't seem to add an empty row because my code is trying to set the information in the cell with data from my specified array, but naturally, the count in the array is different from my data source (as I want the count to be +1).

> **E.g.** I want to return 3 cells even if there are only 2 dictionaries in my array, and the third cell should be empty.

I want this because the third cell allows my user to fill out empty fields, while the fields in the previous two rows are populated with their already input data. Here's how I'm trying to return the extra row right now, but as mentioned above, it crashes my app due to the imbalance of dictionaries returned in my array.

Here's my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   
    self.allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.itemDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

}

//TableView delegates
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
   
    
}




-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return self.allItems.count + 1;

}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    

        static NSString *ClientTableIdentifier = @"InvoiceDetailsTableViewCell";
        
       InvoiceDetailsTableViewCell *cell = (InvoiceDetailsTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ClientTableIdentifier];
        
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InvoiceDetailsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            
        }
    
    if (self.allItems.count == 0) {
        
    } else {
        
        cell.itemName.text = [self.allItems valueForKey:@"Item Name"][indexPath.row];
     
        
    }
    
        return cell;
        
    
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
   InvoiceDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   
    NSString *itemTitle = cell.itemName.text;
    NSString *itemDescrip = cell.itemDescrip.text;
    NSString *itemCost = cell.itemCost.text;
    NSString *itemTax = cell.itemTax.text;
    
    
    [self.itemDetails setValue:itemTitle forKey:@"Item Name"];

    [self.itemDetails setValue:itemDescrip forKey:@"Item Description"];
    
    [self.itemDetails setValue:itemCost forKey:@"Item Cost"];
  
    [self.itemDetails setValue:itemTax forKey:@"Item Tax Rate"];

    [self.allItems addObject:self.itemDetails];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: There are a ton of issues unrelated to your out of bounds problem: 1. Do you really want tapping on some random cell to create a new row? (Usually you'd have a “+” button or, if you started entering text in the last cell, then auto add a new blank cell.) 2. You are using `itemDetails` property to keep track of a `NSDictionary` that you are adding. So you'll be adding the same dictionary again and again. No bueno. ...

Comment: 3. This cell dequeue logic is wrong: You want to register your NIB in `viewDidLoad` and then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will _always_ succeed, and no `if (cell == nil)` test is needed. The way this is written, you will have no cell reuse. 4. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are setting `itemName`, but you need to set all of the `UITextField` properties (in case the cell is reused). 5. You really want to update your model as text fields change, not in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: 6. On a more stylistic note, I would advise against using a `NSMutableDictionary` to contain these four items. I'd suggest a `NSObject` subclass with four properties.

Comment: @Rob What is the benefit of using NSObject vs. NSMutableDictionary? And I don't plan on keeping it "tapping on the cell", I will be adding a button lol. Was trying to simplify the question.

Comment: Re `NSObject` vs `NSMutableDictionary`, the problem with the dictionary is that it does no validation that you supplied the right key. If you use an object with defined properties, you end up with better compile-time validation (the compiler will warn you if you use an incorrect property name). Plus the code is more concise/readable. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/abd3b608b247c3307bd6d7d7484d9a8b for example definition.

Comment: just told, each UITableView has also `self.tableView.tableFooterView` which if not used in other ways is possibly useful as your "third" input handle fake cell because in a tableview with only one section the footerview appears always below the last cell of that section. You could just assign a UIView to it and keep the designs of cells and input separate from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One significant problem is the line that says:

```objectivec
cell.itemName.text = [self.allItems valueForKey:@"Item Name"][indexPath.row];
```

Since your row count exceeds the number of items in your array, you will want to check the row number before accessing the array:

```objectivec
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
if (row < self.allItems.count) {
    cell.itemName.text = self.allItems[row][@"Item Name"]; // personally, I’d get row first, and then keyed value second
} else {
    cell.itemName.text = @"";
}
```

You want to check to make sure that the current row is not the last (blank) row.